# NUnit Assert.AreEqual DateTime Tolerances

Tags: c#, .net-3.5, nunit

I'm wondering if anybody's found a good solution to this:

In our unit tests; we commonly use `Assert.AreEqual()` to validate our results.  All is well and good; until we start trying to use this on DateTime properties.

Although the times are very similar, sometimes they are off by milliseconds, which causes the tests to fail.  In our application; as long as they're accurate to the second; that's good enough for us.

Has anybody found a good way to somehow implement tolerances in this case?  Typically our workaround is to split it into 2 separate statements; one which checks the `.ToShortDateString()`, and another that checks `.ToShortTimeString()`, but this looks sloppy in my opinion.

Answer (score 99, accepted):

You can check tolerances with something like:

```
Debug.Assert((date1 - date2) < TimeSpan.FromSeconds(1));
```

If you are unsure which date is newer, use

```
Debug.Assert(Math.Abs((date1 - date2).TotalSeconds) < 1)
```

NUnit has also added built in support for this using the [`Within`](http://www.nunit.org/index.php?p=equalConstraint&r=2.4.8) keyword

```
DateTime now = DateTime.Now;
DateTime later = now + TimeSpan.FromHours(1.0);

Assert.That(later, Is.EqualTo(now).Within(TimeSpan.FromHours(3.0)));
Assert.That(later, Is.EqualTo(now).Within(3).Hours);
```

Comment: Very nice.  Never thought to implement it this way

Comment: But don't you really mean `<`?

Comment: @Dan Tao - Yeah, had my assert thinking was backward, yeah if u want it to error, then it should <

Comment: This will fail if date2 is larger than date1 by more than a second. Should check the absolute value of the total seconds of the difference. e.g. `Debug.Assert(Math.Abs((date1 - date2).TotalSeconds) < 1)`

Comment: NUnit has in-built support for this, see my answer below http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3577856/nunit-assert-areequal-datetime-tolerances/7601507#7601507

Answer (score 108):

Use **Assert.That** and **Is.Equal** constraint instead of **Assert.AreEqual**. Below is a code sample from the Nunit website itself

```
DateTime now = DateTime.Now;
DateTime later = now + TimeSpan.FromHours(1.0);

Assert.That(now, Is.EqualTo(now) );
Assert.That(later, Is.EqualTo(now).Within(TimeSpan.FromHours(3.0)));
Assert.That(later, Is.EqualTo(now).Within(3).Hours);
```

Comment: Much cleaner solution. If this Assert fails, the message produced will clearly indicate the cause of the failure.

Comment: Why use `Assert.That` instead of `Assert.AreEqual`? Could you give some explanation?

Comment: @kuskmen check out the discussion at https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16086870/assert-that-vs-assert-true
`Assert.That` give you more extensibility and better logging if done correctly.

Answer (score 10):

To correctly check if any 2 arbitrary dates are equals to within a 1 second tolerance, the following is a correct solution:

```
Debug.Assert(Math.Abs((date1 - date2).TotalSeconds) < 1)
```

I figured I'd add this as a solution since the accepted solution was incorrect when `date2` is larger than `date1` by more than a second, and the solution has not been updated following my comment to @SwDevMan81.